# Simple Injector: Cyclic Dependency error in Conditional Decorator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, simple-injector

While refactoring, I was trying to move a lot of functionality from my base repositories to some decorators. For some reason I am getting a cyclic dependency error. The full error is here:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type `IValidator<EntityDTO>` failed. The configuration is invalid. The type `EntityReaderExcludeDefaultEntitiesDecorator` is directly or indirectly depending on itself.

Here is my `IValidator` implementation (Fluent Validation)

```
public class EntityValidator : IValidator<EntityDTO>
{
    private readonly Data.IEntityReader _repo;

    public EntityValidator(Data.IEntityReader repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;

        RuleFor(e => e.GroupId).NotEqual(Guid.Empty)
            .WithMessage("The selected group is invalid");
        // more rules
    }
}
```

Here is my Decorator implementation

```
public class EntityReaderExcludeDefaultEntitiesDecorator : IEntityReader
{
    private readonly IEntityReader _reader;

    public EntityReaderExcludeDefaultEntitiesDecorator(IEntityReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public EntityDTO FindById(Guid id)
    {
        var entity = _reader.FindById(id);
        if (entity.Name.Equals(DocumentConstants.DEFAULT_ENTITY_NAME)) return null;
        return entity;
    }

    // more methods
}
```

And here is my configuration for the decorator

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IEntityWriter), 
    typeof(Service.Decorators.EntityWriterValidationDecorator),
    context => context.Consumer.ServiceType != typeof(IGroupWriter));

// Do not use the decorator in the Document Writer (We need to find the 'None' entity
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IEntityReader), 
    typeof(Service.Decorators.EntityReaderExcludeDefaultEntitiesDecorator),
    context => context.Consumer.ServiceType != typeof(IDocumentWriter));

container.RegisterConditional<IEntityWriter, DocumentEntityWriter>(c => !c.Handled);
container.RegisterConditional<IEntityReader, DocumentEntityReader>(c => !c.Handled);
```

I would give more info but I have no idea why this is. Did I not setup my decorator properly?

I did not include the `IValidator` registration because it is correct. The error seems to be saying the reason we cannot instantiate an `IValidator<EntityDTO>` is because of the `EntityReaderExcludeDefaultEntitiesDecorator` has a dependency issue (Which ended up being the case).

If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The exception message talks about `IValidator<EntityDTO>`, while your code shows an `AbstractValidator<EntityDTO>` and you register an `IEntityReader` in your registration. I am lost.

Comment: @Steven Sorry. I updated it a bit. The IValidator registration is correct, though. That exception seems to be saying that there is an issue with the decorator, and that is why I did not include the IValidator registration. It did not seem pertinent to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding checks to make sure I wasn't injecting the decorator into itself. Is this how it should be done?

```
// Do not validate when adding from a group
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IEntityWriter),
    typeof(Decorators.EntityWriterValidationDecorator),
    context => context.Consumer.ServiceType != typeof(IGroupWriter)
        && context.Consumer.ImplementationType != context.ImplementationType);

// Do not use the decorator in the Document Writer (We need to find the 'None' entity
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IEntityReader),
    typeof(Service.Decorators.EntityReaderExcludeDefaultEntitiesDecorator),
    context => context.Consumer.ServiceType != typeof(IDocumentWriter)
        && context.Consumer.ImplementationType != context.ImplementationType);
```

Comment: What you're doing is correct. `context.ImplementationType` simply returns `typeof(EntityWriterValidationDecorator)`, so your `context.Consumer.ImplementationType != context.ImplementationType` statement simply asks "is the consumer type not the type itself". It would be a bit more self-explanatory if you would change the statement to `context.Consumer.ImplementationType != typeof(EntityWriterValidationDecorator)`.

Comment: @Steven I agree. I will change the statement to be more explicit. Thanks!